# Unit test of angularfirestore service

Tags: angular, angularfire2

How would I write unit test for a service using AngularFirestore?

Currently I have the following:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
export class AngularFireStoreStub extends AngularFirestore {}

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ DataModelService,
        { provide: AngularFirestore, useClass: AngularFireStoreStub },
    ]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([DataModelService], (service: DataModelService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

However this gives me the following error in Jasmine:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AngularFireStoreStub: ([object Object], ?).
```

Since I am relatively new to angular unit testing, this don't help me a lot.

Comment: If your stub class `extends AngularFirestore` then **it has all of the same dependencies**, which you are not providing. It's not really a stub, because it inherits all of the methods and calls through to the real implementation anyway. Why not use e.g. `jasmine.createSpyObj` to create the test double?

Comment: you should be injecting the `AngularFireStore` into the fixture as `angularFirestore = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AngularFirestore);` by declaring the variable as `let angularFirestore:AngularFirestore;`